# Continued Float with Subfigures - Modern Approach?

Tags: floats, subfloats, subfig

I am often working with subfigures like

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots/P0.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:P0}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots/C0.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:C0}
  \end{subfigure}
  \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots/P1.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:P1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots/C1.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:C1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[]{}
  \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
```

But I read in a comment here on tex.stackexchange that the `subfigure` environment is depreciated and outdated (for years). So I was wondering what a modern approach to subfigures looks like? Ideally one that spans over a pagebreak, i.e. compatible with continued floats. I am always happy to learn new stuff to make my documents look better. :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: `subfigure` environment is defined with `subcaption` package. It is now very recommended environment for inserting subfigures in figure. Deprecated is package `subfigure` package, which has different syntax for including of sub figures in figure.

Comment: You can replace the \\ with a \par or blank line.  Inside the figure environment \parindent=0pt and \parskip=0pt.  \caption begins and ends with a \par.